# How to check if data is already in array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, bing, bing-api

I am working on a JavaScript project using Bing-Maps API. The goal of the project is to search for businesses in user's area, and then print their names and phone numbers on the screen. Bing has a limitation of 25 searches per specific area, so I have to constantly move target square so it will get new results. Problem is, very often target squares overlap, and website adds same businesses that it already added before into array. I tried to use almost every javascript function to check for duplicate in array, but no matter what, it keeps adding duplicates into array and there is nothing to stop it.

```js
function GeocodeCallback(response) {
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  let used = [] //Array for posted numbers

  //Chech if phone number has been already posted
  function HasDuplicate(object) {
    for (let i = 0; i < used.length; i++) {
      if (used[i] == object) {
        return true
      }
    }
    return false
  }

  if (response &&
    response.resourceSets &&
    response.resourceSets.length > 0 &&
    response.resourceSets[0].resources) {

    var results = response.resourceSets[0].resources;

    let html = ['<table>'];
    //PROBLEM AREA ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      console.log("Phone " + results[i].PhoneNumber + "Name " + results[i].name)
      if (!HasDuplicate(results[i].PhoneNumber)) {
        console.log("Not Duplicate")
        html.push('<tr><td>' + results[i].name + '</td><td>' + results[i].PhoneNumber + '</td></tr>'); //<td>', results[i].Website, '</td>
        data += results[i].PhoneNumber + " , " + results[i].name + "\n" //Save Data into file
        used.push(results[i].PhoneNumber)
      } else {
        console.log("IsDuplicate " + results[i].name)
      }
    }
    //PROBLEM AREA ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    html.push('</table>');
    output.innerHTML += html.join('');
  } else {
    output.innerHTML = "No results found.";
  }
}
```

When I run this code, 99% of the numbers that it prints it says are not duplicates even though they are, but there is 1% of phone numbers that are marked as duplicates and are not added to array. So my code is able to detect if it's a duplicate or not, but it doesn't do it 100% of the time for some reason. Am I doing the check wrong or is it a problem with Bing Maps Data ?

Here is my full code if you would like to try to replicate the issue. Thank you for your time reading this post, any help will be appreciated.

```js
var map, searchManager;
var BingMapsKey = 'AuV6Kc6hF3yFNL_DXFTDGuSu9DCdIK8zYF208z0eNdqbXtt87UHslIKJ70900Wbj';
let data = "" //String to store data that will be saved 
let userLat, userLong, updatedLat, updatedLong

function GetMap() {
  map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
    credentials: BingMapsKey
  });

  //Load the spatial math module
  Microsoft.Maps.loadModule("Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath", function() {
    //Request the user's location
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var loc = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      userLat = position.coords.latitude
      userLong = position.coords.longitude
      updatedLat = userLat + 0.05
      updatedLong = userLong + 0.05
      geocode()
      //Create an accuracy circle
      var path = Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath.getRegularPolygon(loc, position.coords.accuracy, 36, Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath.Meters);
      var poly = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon(path);
      map.entities.push(poly);

      //Add a pushpin at the user's location.
      var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc);
      map.entities.push(pin);

      //Center the map on the user's location.
      map.setView({
        center: loc,
        zoom: 17
      });
    });
  });
}



function geocode() {
  var query = document.getElementById('input').value;

  //Move around the map and get locations from specific square
  for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    const longlat = [userLat, userLong, updatedLat, updatedLong]
    var geocodeRequest = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/LocalSearch/?query=" + encodeURIComponent(query) + "&userMapView=" + encodeURIComponent(longlat) + "&maxResults=25&jsonp=GeocodeCallback&key=" + BingMapsKey;
    CallRestService(geocodeRequest, GeocodeCallback);
    userLat += 0.05
    userLong += 0.05
    updatedLat += 0.05
    updatedLong += 0.05
  }
}

function GeocodeCallback(response) {
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  let used = [] //Array for posted numbers

  //Chech if phone number has been already posted
  function HasDuplicate(object) {
    for (let i = 0; i < used.length; i++) {
      if (used[i] == object) {
        return true
      }
    }
    return false
  }

  if (response &&
    response.resourceSets &&
    response.resourceSets.length > 0 &&
    response.resourceSets[0].resources) {

    var results = response.resourceSets[0].resources;

    let html = ['<table>'];
    //PROBLEM AREA ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      console.log("Phone " + results[i].PhoneNumber + "Name " + results[i].name)
      if (!HasDuplicate(results[i].PhoneNumber)) {
        console.log("Not Duplicate")
        html.push('<tr><td>' + results[i].name + '</td><td>' + results[i].PhoneNumber + '</td></tr>'); //<td>', results[i].Website, '</td>
        data += results[i].PhoneNumber + " , " + results[i].name + "\n" //Save Data into file
        used.push(results[i].PhoneNumber)
      } else {
        console.log("IsDuplicate " + results[i].name)
      }
    }
    //PROBLEM AREA ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    html.push('</table>');


    output.innerHTML += html.join('');


  } else {
    output.innerHTML = "No results found.";
  }
}

let WriteToFile = () => {

  // Convert the text to BLOB.
  const textToBLOB = new Blob([data], {
    type: 'text/plain'
  });
  const sFileName = 'formData.txt'; // The file to save the data.

  let newLink = document.createElement("a");
  newLink.download = sFileName;

  if (window.webkitURL != null) {
    newLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textToBLOB);
  } else {
    newLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToBLOB);
    newLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(newLink);
  }

  newLink.click();
}

function CallRestService(request) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
  script.setAttribute("src", request);
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

```css
#myMap {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 10px;
}

#center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 10px;
}

#search,
#output {
  margin-left: 20%;
}

.form-control {
  margin: 0 20%;
}

#space {
  margin-left: 17%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Business Search</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap' async defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myMap"></div>

  <h1 class="display-4" id="center">Search for business: </h1>

  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" id="input" class="form-control" value="car">
  </div>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-large" id="search" value="Search" onClick="geocode()">Search</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-large" value="Save" onClick="WriteToFile()">Save</button>

  <div id="output">Name<span id="space">Phone Number</span></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You mean [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)? Or `.find`?

Comment: I tried checking using .includes, but it still keeps printing results into array. I also tried to use indexOf and findIndex, but none of them work. I am going to try to use .find right now, I havent tried that one yet

Comment: Are you sure they're really duplicates? There might be differences in whitespace or punctuation.

Comment: Look at `console.log(used)` to see if they're really duplicates.

Comment: Well thats why I am checking using phone number because Bing formats all numbers the same way, but yes I am sure they are duplicates because on the screen it shows exactly same name and same phone number, even though in my code it's not suppose to show anything on screen

Comment: Is there is a limit on how many items can you add into array in JavaScript ? Because it seems like my app only adds 16 into it

Comment: Okay I think I actually fixed. Thank you very much Barmar, your suggestion lead me to the fix of the problem. I just needed to declare array at the very top of the script so it would be global. I made it local and it kept erasing every time function got called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array used to track the duplicates is being initialized repeatedly for every separate execution of your requests.

```
function GeocodeCallback(response) {
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  let used = [] //<------ This is initialized every time a new result set is arrived
  ...
```

This means it is not going to track duplicates across multiple calls - because it always loses the numbers of the previous call.

The array should be defined outside the callback:

```
let used = [] //Array for posted numbers

function GeocodeCallback(response) {
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
   ...
```

Comment: Yes that was the issue, it worked, thank you very much for your answer